# Can I use multiple POST options (e.g. Form Submission & Fetch()) for the same route in Flask?

Tags: javascript, flask, post, fetch-api

I'm using `fetch()` for the first time, and I'm getting a *415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON* when I try to load my 'calendar' page  - I've seen other posts addressing this topic, but none of the solutions have worked thus far, although I'm sure it may be because of how I'm implementing my code.

I'm also curious as to why in the terminal, the code runs fine (especially the POST request):

`{'test': 'hello', 'number': 1 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2023 20:13:54] "POST /calendar HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

But when I access the page through my form submission, the HTML error occurs:
`127.0.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2023 20:33:04] "POST /calendar HTTP/1.1" 415 -`

**Does the issue involve the fact that I'm using the POST route for both a form submission and fetch POST? Does overlap between the two POST options to the same route create an issue?**

**JavaScript**

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/calendar", {
  method: "POST",
  credentials: "include",
  body: JSON.stringify({test:"hello", number: 1}),
  cache: "no-cache",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
});
```

**Flask**

```
@app.route("/calendar", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def calendar():
    if request.method == "POST":
        stylistInfo = request.form.get("stylistInfo")
        req = request.get_json()
        print(req)
        return render_template('calendar.html', stylistName=stylistInfo)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('calendar.html')
```

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve JSON data with request.form? To fix this issue, you should consider using separate routes or endpoints for handling form submissions and JSON POST requests

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the format of the data is causing the error message.

You send a JSON format with the `fetch` call. However, the form is submitted as urlencoded-formdata.
The query with `request.get_json()` expects an HTTP header containing 'application/json', which is not present when the form is sent.

A solution would be to also send your data via fetch as urlencoded-formdata by transferring a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData?retiredLocale=de) object. This means that all data is sent in the same format and calling `request.get_json()` is unnecessary as everything can be requested from `request.form`.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('test', 'Hello');
formData.append('number', 1);

fetch("/calendar", {
    method: "POST", 
    credentials: "include", 
    body: formData,
    cache: "no-cache",
})
```

However, if you still want to send JSON, you can distinguish based on the HTTP header. [`request.is_json`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Request.is_json) checks whether said header points to JSON data.

```py
def calendar():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.is_json:
            req = request.get_json()
            print(req)
        else:
            stylistInfo = request.form.get("stylistInfo")
            return render_template('calendar.html', stylistName=stylistInfo)
    return render_template("calendar.html")
```